# How to center css menu and get rid of left margin space in ie?

Tags: html, center, css

Thanks for reading this, I have a menu which is centered by padding both left an right of the ul but I think that leaves a bit of white clear space in IE on the left

It looks ok in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but in IE (every version) has space and its not centered

here is the HTML

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li id="current"><a href="#">Strona Glowna</a></li>
<li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Wlasciciel</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>                
</ul>
</div>
```

And the css

```css
.menu {
  border:none;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:opx;
  font: 100% Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:900;
}
.menu ul {
  background:#333333;
  height:35px;
  list-style:none;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0 242px 0;
  }
.menu li {
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    }
.menu li a {
    background:#333333 url("images/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:35px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 25px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    .menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a {
        background: #FF0000 url("images/hover.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        }

.menu li ul {
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    z-index:200;
    }
.menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    }
.menu li li {
    background:url('images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:225px;
    }
.menu li:hover li a {
    background:none;
    }
.menu li ul a {
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    }
    .menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a {
        background:#2580a2 url('images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
        border:0px;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
    .menu li ul #current {
    background:#2580a2 url('images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
.menu p {
    clear:left;
    }
```

A live demo can be found under [adamlisik.co.uk/kantor](http://adamlisik.co.uk/kantor)

Thanks for all your help

Comment: You seem to have a `padding` of `opx` instead of `0px` in your CSS for `.menu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```